# XML tree printer?

Tags: c++, xml, data-structures, tree

Is there a program that will print a nicely formatted tree from XML data?

I am working on a B+ tree programming assignment for class and it would greatly help if I could visualize the tree.  It wouldn't be too hard to output my internal data structure to XML (see below) if there was a program that would render it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you instead output in [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) format (called [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html)). This can give [very pretty results](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.html), and it has had lots of effort spent on its layout routines. A more general-purpose XML visualizer might not have.

Answer (score 0):

Just what kind of visualization are you after? If you just want to be able to expand and collapse elements with syntax highlighting then any XML viewer/editor will give you that functionality (hell, even IE can do this natively).
Also, if you can convert to XML you might consider converting to HTML and just visualizing the data that way.